# How to set active tab using crispy form?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have the following code snippet to show the tabs using crispy form in a modelform. Is it possible to set the active tab when the page loads? I put the `css_class='Active"` in the second tab, but it seems not working. Thanks in advance

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
                common_layout,
                TabHolder(
                    Tab(
                        'Tab1',
                        Field('name', readonly=True),
                        Field('age', readonly=True),

                    ),
                    Tab(
                        'class',
                        Field('grade 1'),
                        css_class="Active",
                    ),
            )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

active should be lowercase

```
# ...
Tab(
    'class',
    Field('grade 1'),
    css_class="active",
),
#...
```